# Web API - return error code if required fied in request is missing

Tags: serialization, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

When using ASP.NET WebAPI 2 is there any way to throw an error if request does not contain required field? Current behavior is to put default value to the missing field. It the any way to change it?

As per Json.NET documentation there is special configuration setting:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MissingMemberHandling.htm
but setting it does not give much difference.

Code samples:
At App_Start

```
var  config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
```

At controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/post-guid")]
    public TestResponse Post(RequestWithGuid request) {
        if(request == null) {
            throw  new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        // This check will work but I am trying to omit it
        // with serializer settings to not put default values for missing members.
        //if(request.id == default(Guid)) {
        //    throw  new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        //}

        return new TestResponse {
            id = request.id
        };
    }

public class RequestWithGuid {
    public Guid id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate `id` field as `Required` Guid. Something like:

```
public class RequestWithGuid 
{
   [Required]
   public Guid id {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your controller method, you can validate the model:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid){
   throw  new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Better yet, you can create a validation filter and decorate all your methods like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/post-guid")]
[ValidateModel]
public TestResponse Post(RequestWithGuid request) {
    ...
}
```

And your action filter class:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid request");

        }
    }
```

Comment: if (!ModelState.IsValid){
   throw  new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
} this part I am actually try to omit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

At Application_Start I have described missing member must be handled as error and setup error handling.

```
var  config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Error = _serializationErrorHandler;
```

And created error handler at Global.asax.cs

```
private readonly EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> _serializationErrorHandler = (sender, args) => {
    _log.Error("Serialization Error", args.ErrorContext.Error);
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
};
```

Comment: That might be an issue for consumers of your API as there will be times that they don't want to include non-required fields.

Comment: Depends fully who your consumers are and whether you want to architecturally optimize for correctness / system integrity VS minimal bandwidth.

In a public-facing API, you don't control your consumers and thus want to be able to likely handle anything and everything. In an internal API (you control all client apps), it is likely better to be explicit about everything that gets passed in. An empty field should thus be passed in as '"Field" = null" in JSON and not just omitted – which is likely a mistake/oversight and should be treated as such.